# '1 more comment' but no more comments

Tags: bug, comments

The following post has 'show 1 more comment' link, but, when I click it, there are no more comments:

- [**Why is the de-icing fluid sprayed on jets coloured orange?**](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9376/why-is-the-de-icing-fluid-sprayed-on-jets-coloured-orange/9381#9381)

Update: 8 hours later (02:15UTC), and there is still a 'broken' reference to *'show 1 more comment'*

[image]

Clicked:

[image]

Comment: <s>Perhaps the comment is deleted between the time you saw the notice and you clicked, but we'll need a dev, a CM or an Aviation moderator to confirm that.</s> Nevermind, also reproduced. Looks unlikely that this will happen twice.

Comment: @ProgramFOX - I confirmed multiple times, Refreshed, etc. and got multiple people to check as well... unless we are all missing something... did you click the link?

Comment: @ProgramFOX was reproduced with minimum 3 separate users, one of them me

Comment: @Vogel612'sShadow and rolfl: I also reproduced now. Nevermind my previous comment.

Comment: Btw, norepro on the android app...

Comment: @rolfl your link has extra stuff after it, I tried http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9376/why-is-the-de-icing-fluid-sprayed-on-jets-coloured-orange/ and it was still there as well. this is versus http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9376/why-is-the-de-icing-fluid-sprayed-on-jets-coloured-orange/9381#9381

Comment: @Fish not sure yet, better wait for a day and if this resolves on its own, that's most likely the same case indeed.

Comment: Currently 02:14Z and still affected.... that's almost 8 hours.

Comment: Aaannnndddd.... it's gone.